# Why my PHP preg_match matching the second subpattern instead of the first one?

Tags: php, preg-match

My PHP code is:

```
$pattern = '/(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)(,| )[\d]{1,2}[A-Z]{1,1}[a-z]{2,2}/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
    $name = str_replace("(M1) ", "", substr($content, 0, $matches[0][1]));
    $date = substr($content, $matches[0][1], 15);
}
```

It works fine with one match sub pattern.Like:

```
  
B'Meadow Alarm Tue,17Sep 19:48 Ur001 General User Closing By User 
name:  B'Meadow Alarm  
date:  Tue,17Sep 19:48
```

My string is:

```
(M1) B'Meadow Alarm Tue,17Sep 19:48 Ur001 General User Closing By User (M2) B'Meadow Alarm Tue,18Nov 09:18 Ur001 General User Closing By User
```

it is supposed to be:

```
name:  B'Meadow Alarm  
date:  Tue,17Sep 19:48
```

But the reality result is:

```
name:  B'Meadow Alarm Tue,17Sep 19:48 Ur001 General User Closing By User (M2) B'Meadow Alarm  
date:  Tue,18Nov 09:18
```

Question: What is wrong in my pattern? or code?

**----------**

### Edit

Sorry, guys! One of my colleague changed this regular expression on Server's repository to following one:
'/(.*)(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)(,| )[\d]{1,2}[A-Z]{1,1}[a-z]{2,2}(.*)/';

But he doesn't commit to git. That is why I can't see these changes in my local repository.
the (.*) cause the problem.

Comment: do you mean preg_match_all? because preg_match wouldn't return a nested array `$matches[0][1]` wouldn't be there.

Comment: I got your expected result `B'Meadow Alarm` and `Tue,17Sep 19:48`. Your codes worked

Comment: also, what is the value of `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`? because that might be the culprit

Comment: no issue with the code, it should show what you want it to show,

Comment: @Bora Thanks! I am still struggle on this problem. ^_^

Comment: Sorry guys! Someone in my company touched my server repository and never mention to me! I just use my local repository to debugging!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your pattern or code is wrong. Your code output exactly as supposed to be.

Comment: This not answers OP's question - so should be a comment

Comment: Sorry! Someone in my company touched my server repository and never mention to me! I just use my local repository to debugging!!!!!!!!!!!